# Dell Vostro 1520 wifi not working with Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, wireless, dell

I have installed Ubuntu 12.04 on Dell Vostro 1520 Laptop. But found Wifi is hardware locked, though wifi is working perfectly fine with Windows 7 in the same laptop.

I tried to upgrade the drivers as mentioned in other posts/forums but could not resolve the issue.

I had the similar problem with versions 11.* as well. Last time the Wifi worked with 10.* version.

Please help me to get it resolved.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! We need more hardware information to help you, can you look at [this question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/14008/i-have-a-hardware-detection-problem-what-logs-do-i-need-to-look-into) and then edit your question adding the information.

Answer (score 1):

I have a Vostro 1520 on which I just upgraded to 12.04. Even though my wifi was working on 10.04, I have to re-do what I've done on 10.04... Here it is:

```
sudo rmmod dell_laptop
```

At this point, wireless indicator will light up and after a while, you'll be able to connect to the available wi-fi access points. However, the dell_laptop kernel module will get loaded again on bootup and hence, the fix is not permanent. Let's make it so:

```
echo 'blacklist dell_laptop' | sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-custom
```

Wireless should be working fine from now on.

It did on my laptop.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

I had a hard time making the WiFi work after installing Ubuntu 12.10 on Dell XPS. Running `rfkill list all` always returned:

```
0: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: yes
```

After trying almost everyone of the tons of suggestions about this problem on the Ubuntu forums, and none of them worked form, I simply tried <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> (the <kbd>F2</kbd> key has the WiFi sign) and the problem disappeared.

The simple solution (unless you have a deeper problem) is <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> (or whatever key with the WiFi sign).

Answer (score 0):

I also faced the same problem when upgraded to 11.10.
I tried the auto updating using the hard line -ethernet cable - , but didn't work.
After some research I finally made it. In the end, these commands made my day.

To make this work, your must be connected to Internet, so use LAN cable.

```
sudo apt-get purge bcmwl-kernel-source broadcom-sta-common broadcom-sta-source
sudo apt-get install b43-fwcutter firmware-b43-installer
```

Then reboot.