# dell inspiron 1440 no wifi ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, dell, inspiron

I used ubuntu for several months before the update came around and ever since then my wifi has been unable to connect (let alone i can not see any available connections either). I have read everything online and followed all the code that everyone has advised yet nothing seems to work. somebody save me before i whack this computer. any suggestions are great ones

Comment: Could you post your wifi vendor/model? Open a terminal and launch "lspci". Copy and paste the out.

Comment: saadster@saadster-Inspiron-1440:~$ lspci
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Mobile 4 Series Chipset Memory Controller Hub (rev 07)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Mobile 4 Series Chipset Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 07)
00:02.1 Display controller: Intel Corporation Mobile 4 Series Chipset Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 07)
00:1a.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family)

Comment: USB UHCI Controller #4 (rev 03)
00:1a.1 USB controller: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) USB UHCI Controller #5 (rev 03)
00:1a.2 USB controller: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) USB UHCI Controller #6 (rev 03)
00:1a.7 USB controller: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) USB2 EHCI Controller #2 (rev 03)
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) HD Audio Controller (rev 03)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) PCI Express Port 1 (rev 03)
00:1c.1 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) PCI Express Port 2 (rev 03)

Comment: 00:1c.2 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) PCI Express Port 3 (rev 03)
00:1c.4 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) PCI Express Port 5 (rev 03)
00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) USB UHCI Controller #1 (rev 03)
00:1d.1 USB controller: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) USB UHCI Controller #2 (rev 03)
00:1d.2 USB controller: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) USB UHCI Controller #3 (rev 03)
00:1d.7 USB controller: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) USB2 EHCI Controller #1 (rev 03)

Comment: 00:1e.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 82801 Mobile PCI Bridge (rev 93)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation ICH9M LPC Interface Controller (rev 03)
00:1f.2 SATA controller: Intel Corporation 82801IBM/IEM (ICH9M/ICH9M-E) 4 port SATA Controller [AHCI mode] (rev 03)
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) SMBus Controller (rev 03)
09:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8101E/RTL8102E PCI Express Fast Ethernet controller (rev 02)
0c:00.0 Network controller: Broadcom Corporation BCM4312 802.11b/g LP-PHY (rev 01)

Comment: Please put this information in your question, not in the comments, no one can read that!

Answer (score 0):

I had problem with my dell laptop and wifi almost in all releases after 10.04. My solution was to use another network to update my drivers. However, last time, I followed the instruction of this post and it worked. Checked it out:

[Dell Vostro 1520 wifi not working with Ubuntu 12.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/141423/dell-vostro-1520-wifi-not-working-with-ubuntu-12-04)

Comment: Unfortunately that didnt help out my situation, thanks though

Answer (score 0):

I'm using the same LapTop (Dell Inspiron 1440) and I had the same problem, and used many ways but with no luck. Until I found this post.
http://www.mindwerks.net/2012/06/wireless-bcm4312-with-the-3-4-and-3-5-kernel/

But I modified the last step a little.

After running "make" in terminal, I followed this step using the Readme file from this address:
http://www.broadcom.com/support/802.11/linux_sta.php

"

> 2: Insmod the driver.
>
> Otherwise, if you have not previously installed a wl driver, you'll need
> to add a security module before using the wl module.  Most newer systems
> use lib80211 while others use ieee80211_crypt_tkip. See which one works for
> your system.
>
> ## modprobe lib80211
>
> or
>
> ## modprobe ieee80211_crypt_tkip
>
> If your using the cfg80211 version of the driver, then cfg80211 needs to be
> loaded:
>
> ## modprobe cfg80211
>
> Then:
>
> ## insmod wl.ko
>
> wl.ko is now operational.  It may take several seconds for the Network
> Manager to notice a new network driver has been installed and show the
> surrounding wireless networks."

And if you encountered an error, this README file has solutions for a couple of them.